# Format of rsync logfile

Tags: backup, rsync, logfile

I am running a backup with `rsync` during which a logfile is created. However, I do not know what the abbreviations mean. Here is a sample of the logfile:

```
2016/11/15 15:17:53 [4906] building file list
2016/11/15 15:17:53 [4906] .d..t...... ./
2016/11/15 15:17:53 [4906] >fcst...... .hiddenfile
2016/11/15 15:17:53 [4906] >fcst...... file1
```

What, e.g., does `>fcst......` stand for? More importantly, where is it documented? I did not find it in the manpage. If it actually is in the manpage then please point out the according section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manual page for `rsync` explains it pretty well:

> The update types that replace the Y are as follows:
>
> - A `<` means that a file is being transferred to the remote host
>     (sent).
> - A `>` means that a file is being transferred to the local host
>     (received).
> - A `c` means that a local change/creation is occurring for the
>     item (such as the creation of a directory or the changing of a
>     symlink, etc.).
> - A `h` means that the item is a hard link to another item
>     (requires --hard-links).
> - A `.` means that the item is not being updated (though it might
>     have attributes that are being modified).
> - A `*` means that the rest of the itemized-output area contains
>     a message (e.g. "deleting").
>
>   The file-types that replace the X are: `f` for a file, a `d` for a
>     directory, an `L` for a symlink, a `D` for a device, and a `S` for a special
>     file (e.g. named sockets and fifos).
>
>   The  other  letters  in the string above are the actual letters that
>     will be output if the associated attribute for the item is being
>     updated or a "." for no change.  Three exceptions to this   are: (1) a
>     newly created item replaces each letter with a "+", (2) an identical
>     item replaces the dots with spaces, and (3) an unknown attribute
>     replaces each letter with a "?" (this can hap‐   pen when talking to
>     an older rsync).
>
>   The attribute that is associated with each letter is as follows:
> - A  `c` means either that a regular file has a different
>     checksum (requires --checksum) or that a symlink, device, or special
>     file has a changed value.  Note that if you are sending files
>          to an rsync prior to 3.0.1, this change flag will be present only for checksum-differing regular files.
> - A `s` means the size of a regular file is different and will be
>     updated by the file transfer.
> - A `t` means the modification time is different and is being
>     updated to the sender’s value (requires --times).  An alternate value
>     of T means that the modification time will be set to the
>          transfer  time, which happens when a file/symlink/device is updated without --times and when a symlink is changed and the receiver
>     can’t set its time.  (Note: when using an rsync 3.0.0
>          client, you might see the s flag combined with t instead of the proper T flag for this time-setting failure.)
> - A `p` means the permissions are different and are being updated
>     to the sender’s value (requires --perms).
> - An o means the owner is different and is being updated to the
>     sender’s value (requires --owner and super-user privileges).
> - A `g` means the group is different and is being updated to the
>     sender’s value (requires --group and the authority to set the group).
> - The `u` slot is reserved for future use.
> - The `a` means that the ACL information changed.
> - The `x` means that the extended attribute information changed.

Comment: You can't really blame the OP or anyone else for not finding this on the rsync man page. The current man page is 4,286 lines. Andrew Tridgell's original rsync man page was about 300 lines, after removing the nroff/troff typesettng instructions.